# What is the proper way to index a column in MySQL that has a lot of json data in it?

Tags: mysql, index, json

We have a long row that includes a json column that holds variable columns specific to each row.

We currently do not index that column as we don't query against it - rather it is supporting data for the result.

That table is now over 100,000 rows and pulling results from it is painfully slow.

We pull the data using its primary key - which is indexed, with a result set no larger than 200, but even at 20... it is very slow.

Slow in the reference is 5-20+ seconds.

The json data is not too large (we have blobs in other tables that are much larger and don't see a performance hit).

Is it a mistake to mark it as a json field? Should we just make it a long text field instead (since we do not actually query the data within it?) and avoid the overhead on the server? Or is there some index setting we are missing to ensure json fields are optimized for data pulls whether or not they are being queried...

Here is the structure of that table:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

---

--  Table structure for `caches`

---

CREATE TABLE `caches` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audit_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `audit_key` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `building_key` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `building_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `building_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_key` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `amenity_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `lead_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_key` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_text` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_text_plural` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `program_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_file_status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_nlt_status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_lt_status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_sd_status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_file_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_file_completed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_nlt_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_nlt_completed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_lt_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_lt_completed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_sd_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finding_sd_completed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `followup_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `followup_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `auditors_json` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `amenities_json` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `findings_json` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `amenity_inspection_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `audit_id` (`audit_id`),
  KEY `audit_key` (`audit_key`),
  KEY `building_key` (`building_key`),
  KEY `building_id` (`building_id`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
  KEY `project_key` (`project_key`),
  KEY `amenity_id` (`amenity_id`),
  KEY `lead_id` (`lead_id`),
  KEY `lead_key` (`lead_key`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `finding_file_status` (`finding_file_status`),
  KEY `finding_nlt_status` (`finding_nlt_status`),
  KEY `finding_lt_status` (`finding_lt_status`),
  KEY `followup_date` (`followup_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1019212 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: We need to see that slow `SELECT`.

Comment: Explain why `audit`, `building`, etc have `id`, `key`, and sometimes `name`.  Normally you would have only the `id` in this table; plus another table with the other columns.

Comment: @RickJames one is the local id (in MySsql) - the other is the key from the sync'd  API source record

Comment: Is there a table of "audits"?  With PK(audit_id)?  And column audit_key?

Comment: @rick - SELECT * FROM caches WHERE audit_id = 123

Comment: the PK on the audits table is id -- this is a laravel framework so we use their naming convention - it does also have an audit_key on it as well. Keys are only used to find the records associated to the sync API and update them as needed. Not all records have a key if they were not sourced from the API.

Comment: Redundant data (`audit_key` in two tables) is a general no-no in database design.  You can get the value with a simple `JOIN`; having a copy is risking divergence.  (Yeah, there are valid exceptions.)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM caches WHERE audit_id = 123` should not take more than a second for a hundred rows.  How many rows have that value?  Is there a `LIMIT` clause?  Is Laravel using "lazy" or not-lazy fetching?  Do you need all the columns (`*`)? -- that can also be a source of inefficiency.

Comment: We clearly have the json setup incorrectly - removing that column in a test database returns result (1000 at a time) in less than a second. I will need to look and check our JSON formatting and such @RickJames thanks for your time in helping us diagnose this.

Comment: Typically, if a column is large enough to be stored off-record, you can still read at a rate of 100 rows per second.  Your number sounded much worse than that.  How big is the typical json string?